# 'composer install' command fails on Docker giving 'SSL Operation Failed with code 1' error

Tags: php, docker, ssl, curl, openssl

I am on the Windows machine, with Docker running. Docker image is `FROM php:7.3-apache`.

with

> System : Linux b6df004de9df 4.9.184-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Jul 2 22:58:16
>   UTC 2019 x86_64

having Composer installed in this container successfully with Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32.

Now, I entered into the `bash` of the container and entered a command **$ composer init** which run successfully and initialized the composer, however, upon **$ composer install** command, it gives an error

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. Open   SSL Error
>   messages:   error:1416F086:SSL
>   routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>   Failed to enable crypto   failed to open stream: operation failed

As I could see its an OpenSSL error for Certificate, I tried to get exact error :

> root@b6df004de9df:/var/www/html/my_JSON_proj# openssl s_client
>   -connect www.google.com:443 CONNECTED(00000003) depth=2 C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler
>   Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) , emailAddress =
>   support@zscaler.com
>   **verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate**

To re-confirm, I again tried :

> root@b6df004de9df:/var/www/html/my_JSON_proj# curl https://google.com
>   **curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

Openssl Version: OpenSSL 1.1.0k  28 May 2019

Output of **openssl_get_cert_locations**() :

```
array(8) {
["default_cert_file"]=> "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem"
["default_cert_file_env"]=> "SSL_CERT_FILE"
["default_cert_dir"]=> "/usr/lib/ssl/certs"
["default_cert_dir_env"]=> "SSL_CERT_DIR"
["default_private_dir"]=> "/usr/lib/ssl/private"
["default_default_cert_area"]=> "/usr/lib/ssl"
["ini_cafile"]=> ""
["ini_capath"]=> ""
}
```

So to solve this **Solutions I tried**:

1. I created my localhost certificate Ref: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/openssl-quick-reference-guide.htm#:~:targetText=OpenSSL%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,and%20how%20to%20use%20them. but not sure when to put that certificate so placed in **/usr/local/share/ca-certifcates/** folder and tried 
   **curl https://google.com/ --cacert /usr/local/share/ca-certifcates/localhost.pem** - still same error
2. Edited my **/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini** php configuration file to add

`curl.cainfo="/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.pem"`

`openssl.cafile = "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/localhost.pem"`
just to find the - same error

I have been trying this with no luck.  I have literally scanned through almost all of stack overflow posts related to curl, OpenSSL, SSL, Docker, etc and couldn't find the answer.

- *FURTHER UPDATES & FINDINGS*

  4. Surprisingly I wonder, the 'cacert.pem' the file provided at https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem (note - http**s**) to solve the SSL problem, whereas I am not able to connect to secure links, how can I even get to download pem file from https?  kinda deadlock?  Anyways, so I tried to download using `wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` a non-secure way to get the pem file and I got the output as :

```
root@b6df004de9df:/usr/local/etc/openssl# wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
--2019-11-08 10:21:30--  http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Resolving curl.haxx.se (curl.haxx.se)... 151.101.38.49, 2a04:4e42:9::561
Connecting to curl.haxx.se (curl.haxx.se)|151.101.38.49|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem [following]
--2019-11-08 10:21:31--  https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Connecting to curl.haxx.se (curl.haxx.se)|151.101.38.49|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of 'curl.haxx.se' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'curl.haxx.se' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

And since its a Linux server and no GUI available, so seems an only possible way for me to download is via Terminal, not a browser.

That being said, I manually created cacert.pem file and entered content in it from curl.haxx.se.  And then updated php.ini with the following changes and restarted the apache server.

`curl.cainfo: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cacert.pem` &
`openssl.cafile:  /usr/local/etc/openssl/cacert.pem`
Still - **curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

5. Updated php.ini for curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile with "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem" as its "default_cert_file" according to 'openssl_get_cert_locations()'. Restarted apache server.  Tried with `curl https://www.google.com` - Still **curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**
6. Created a new directory 'ssl' as it was not present already and assuming, By default, the OpenSSL directory is `/usr/local/ssl`. Created cacert.pem file in that folder.  Updated curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile entries in php.ini with this new updated path.  To be on a safer side, executed `update-ca-certificates --fresh` just in case. Restarted the apache server.  Tried with `curl https://www.google.com` - Still **curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

**On side note full output of cURL command** :

```
root@b6df004de9df:/usr/lib/ssl/certs# curl https://thawte.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
root@b6df004de9df:/usr/lib/ssl/certs# openssl s_client -connect thawte.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net)
, emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Utah/serialNumber=5299537-0142/C=US/ST=Utah/
L=Lehi/O=DigiCert, Inc./OU=IT/CN=thawte.com
   i:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t)
 1 s:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t)
   i:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net)/emailAddress=su
pport@zscaler.com
 2 s:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net)/emailAddress=su
pport@zscaler.com
   i:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Root CA/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGpzCCBY+gAwIBAgIQv2zANBgkqhkiG9w0XcVFbs+k59YwRwR4v+pBAQsFADCB
jTELMAkMxEzARBgNVBAgGA1UEBhMCVVTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFTATBgNVBAoTDFpz
... few more lines ...
vxrc40H5bMPW/NgnBjRtUEPnAx9b3ll/sj3KfhbxU0bgnEYNMLb+nwnK6NDZRFpC
5E3fG+TFc9ehaBcF5xWttKz28Wr2nUUhMLhC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Utah/serialNumber=5299537-0142/C=US/ST=Ut
ah/L=Lehi/O=DigiCert, Inc./OU=IT/CN=thawte.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t)
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4270 bytes and written 326 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 06D54188D4F60C7746664262F72361EFE8DC728E9D37FDB25641A28C226DE83C3C574C781A0E4A268A7AEB6187EF54BF
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1573209517
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
read:errno=0
```

**Current DockerFile using to build the image :**

```
FROM php:7.3-apache 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y sendmail libpng-dev

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev 
        libbz2-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libxpm-dev \
        libvpx-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        && \

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        bz2 \
        exif \
        ftp \
        gd \
        gettext \
        mbstring \
        mcrypt \
        mysqli \
        opcache \
        pdo_mysql \
        shmop \
        sockets \
        sysvmsg \
        sysvsem \
        sysvshm \
        zip \
        p7zip-full \
    && \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got the issue sorted out.  Actually, I never had to set the `curl.cainfo` OR `openssl.cafile` or any other updates for that matter like downloading the certificate to use in container etc.  [After I create a Self Signed Certificate](http://www.sandiptekale.com/blog/how-create-self-signed-ssl-certificate-apache-debian-9), I had to **Configure Apache to Use SSL** and **Make those changes related SSL into Apache server** and we're all set.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

1.Add this to your Dockerfile and build the image again

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4
```

2.Download certificate via browser, and copy it to the container
read about [Mount volume (-v, --read-only)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

3.use wget in insecure mode (not recommended) - use flag `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: **1.**Updated Dockerfile to build the image again : 
```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-openssl-dev but 7.64.0-4 is to be installed
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Conflicts: libcurl4-gnutls-dev but 7.64.0-4 is to be installed
```
**2.**Downloaded certificate via browser on my windows machine but not able to pass the file into the container. kinda lost in there.
**3.**Use wget for downloading cert file ? If so, I tried that as well, and gives empty file.

Comment: @SandipT use approad 2 and mount the volume, so if you copy the certificate on the host machine to the directory that you mount it will be visible under docker image dir that you used to mount the volume.

Comment: oh that.. well yeah, I did that... but then, after I download and access in container, I ain't sure where to put that cert/pem file I downloaded in containers folder for final usage, so that it would be always used by system and "composer install" command will seamlessly work.  You see, I can't pass location of certificate file always since composer install uses secured urls indirectly, and since system is not picking of the certificate file no matter what folder I put in, it turns out to be a fruitless work.  I hope I am clear in my explanation.

Comment: ok, further updates on findings... As @Jimmix you suggested, downloaded file on my windows host, copied into C:>www folder which is mapped to /var/www/html folder in container.  Then updated php.ini, set curl.cainfo = /var/www/html/cacert.pem, restarted apache and executed 'curl https ://thawte.com' - still error "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". Even tried 'curl https ://thawte.com --cacert /var/www/html/cacert.pem' from command line, pretty straight cmd, and still "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are behind a proxy (Zscaler), try getting the certificates and update them, steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011298/5078874